# Lateral join on Type ORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am using TypeORM on my app and I encounter a problem trying to query a view that I created that has a json column. I am working with a PostgreSQL v 10.

I have a view call inventory_list made of:

```
id (uuid) sku (varchar) product_name (varchar) product_locations (json)
```

Example record:

```
(id, sku, product_name, product_locations) values ('ID", '233', 'french fries', [{"locationId" : "ID", "locationName" : "Back Room", "cost" : 0.0000, "value" : 0.0000, "retailValue" : 1620.0000}]
```

I use this view to fill a data table (UI) which has filters, and one of the filters are the **locationId**.

I try to query on Datagrip and I found the solution (I think is accurate for this case).

```
SELECT * from inventory_list il JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(il.product_locations) obj(val) ON obj.val->>'locationId' = 'ID'
```

The problem is that I could not recreate this query on my code.

How can I create this query with TypeORM?
If not or you think that is a better approach please let me know!
I spent the hole day trying to figure it out a solution for this but I could not :(

Thank you in advance!!